# SQL Select from an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Is there an easy way to select from a (long) array?
I want something like this

```
SELECT citizenship, count(1) 
FROM table 
WHERE year(date) = 2018 
GROUP BY citizenship
```

But I want all citizenship as column and all dates (from 2000 until as 2018) as rows so I can delete the where clause.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: add  a data sample of your array ..  (at least)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use PIVOT columns.

Heres what I think you want... ( in SQL Server)
See this article: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-rows-to-columns-pivot-and-columns-to-rows-unpivot-in-sql-server.html

Applied to you that could be...

```
    --Declare necessary variables
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([citizenship])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [citizenship] FROM [dbo].[table]) AS PivotExample


--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N'SELECT [Year], ' +   @PivotColumns + '
    FROM (SELECT [citizenship], YEAR([Date]) AS [Year], COUNT(1) As Counter 
          FROM [Table] GROUP BY [citizenship], YEAR([Date])) AS A
    PIVOT( SUM(Counter) 
          FOR [citizenship] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS P'

SELECT   @SQLQuery
--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Adding *distinct* will give you list of unique citizens

```
SELECT distinct citizenship
FROM table 
WHERE year(date) >= 2000 and year(date) <= 2018
```